# Kentico upload a file using the API to a Page Type's File field

Tags: kentico

I have a page type (let's call it `MyPageType`) with a field `PreviewImage` that is of data type `File`.

I am trying to use the Kentico APIs to upload files from the server to that `PreviewImage` field on the `MyPageType` page type. From what I can see it seems that I have to upload the file *somewhere* and then the uploaded file will have a `GUID` that I can use for the `PreviewImage` field.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.kentico.com/api11/content-management/attachments#Attachments-Insertingattachmentsintopagefields

Here's your API example from documentation to insert an attachment into a page type field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Trevor, but I am trying to upload a meta file not an attachment. If you add a file to a File field type through the portal engine then it does not get added to the page's attachments.

Comment: If you are using a field of File type, then the file is a page attachment not a metafile. Metafiles are e.g. the teaser images for web parts or page templates.There are three types of attachments - grouped, unsorted and file field. Anyway, you can take inspiration from the Products API sample: 
// Creates a metafile object storing the e-product file
MetaFileInfo metafile = new MetaFileInfo(eProductFile, newProduct.SKUID, "ecommerce.sku", "E-product");
// Saves the metafile to the database
MetaFileInfoProvider.SetMetaFileInfo(metafile);